# How can I use date function with reserve word?

Tags: php, date, reserved-words

Need to know how can I simply use the `date` function with a reserved word?

See this code:

```
echo date("Y-m-dTH:i:s"); // "2012-08-24EST12:35:46" -> It's wrong.

echo date("Y-m-d")."T".date("H:i:s"); // It's correct, But Not my style.
```

I want to get this string `2012-08-23T14:01:02`, but When I use `T` in the `FORMAT` string.
The result is not what I want. (Because `T` is reserve word)

How to use `T` string with `date` function?

Answer (score 4):

You could escape them with `\`.

```
echo date('Y-m-d\TH:i:s');
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your quick and simple answer.